# $http request param that ignores the current cache, but caches the new data it gets

Tags: angularjs

`$http` request with `cache:false` will ignore cache and get fresh data from a backend service.

On the other hand,

`$http` request with `cache:true` will use the currently existing cache if available, or if no data is in cache, it will get new data and cache it.

**Is there a flag/params I can pass into `$http.get(...)` that either(or both ;) ):**

1)clears the currently existing cache and continues on to make the $http request...and caches this request

2)Ignores the current cache, makes a `$http.get(...)` request, and replaces the currently cached data with the new data.

btw, I know I can use `$cacheFactory` to easily achieve this, but don't really want to.

Here's a simple plunkr that explains this: http://plnkr.co/edit/wu8iz9?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Use services to do that.

**DataService.js**

```
var promise;

this.emptyCache = function () {
  promise = null;
};

this.getData = function (isFreshCallNeeded) {
  if (isFreshCallNeeded) { this.emptyCache(); }

  if (promise) { return promise; }

  promise = $http({url: '', method: 'GET'}).then(function (data) { return data; });
  return promise;
};
```

In **controller**, inject the service and use it as follows:

```
// for first time, makes call and return promise
DataService.getData().then(function(data) {console.log(data)}); 
// second time, makes no call and return promise cached earlier
DataService.getData().then(function(data) {console.log(data)});

var isFreshCallNeeded = true;
// clears the cache, makes a call and return new promise
DataService.getData(isFreshCallNeeded).then(function(data) {console.log(data)}); 

// makes no call and return old saved promise
DataService.getData().then(function(data) {console.log(data)});
```

Comment: thanks. I did think about using a service, but I'm really looking to using $http's caching params to do the trick...